# Unable to extract .NET Single File Application in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I did create a single file application with C#. I have this executable located in a repository and I push it as an artifact. The former is used in build pipelines where I simply add the repo so I can use it. The latter is to use it as an artifact for a release pipeline.

Now during a build pipeline I can simply use it, have tested it and it works. Not really important but the application does 2 things, it sends out mails and updates work items.

When using that exact same application in a release pipeline I get the following error:

> Failure extracting contents of the application bundle.
> I/O failure when writing extracted files.

I don't know for sure, but could this have something to do with the release pipeline's agent running in a containerized environment? The reason I am asking so is because someone else had such an issue while using this approach on AWS with containers, see this [Reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/k8925u/net_single_file_executable_not_compatible_with_ecs/)

[UPDATE] 
The release pipeline was running on a self-hosted Azure DevOps agent. The environment where it is installed on has no .NET 5 runtime nor SDK installed. But I expect the single file application to contain the runtime as well, or am I wrong?

Comment: What exact version of .NET 5 is this? The error is coming from here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/65fdc453d54fd172d60e4b7f1aa30f2ee9df8a44/src/installer/corehost/cli/bundle/extractor.cpp#L95-L110. The error message means that the `fwrite` function has failed, which generally means the system couldn't write a file to disk. Can you tell us more about the file system in use for `$HOME` inside the container? Can you try setting the environment variable `DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR` to some other location within the container?

Comment: @omajid it is not running on a container. I did miss some information as well when posting this issue. It is running on a self-hosted agent. And on the agent no runtime was installed for .NET 5, don't know if that has caused the error? Should expect a single file application to be able to run although the runtime is not installed (it's included right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did publish my application as a simple folder publish. Then putting all the files within the publish folder in the Azure DevOps repository. 
Next I pushed all those files as an artifact with a build pipeline, had to install the .NET 5 current runtime on the environment as the release pipeline is running on a self-hosted agent, and then I am able to run the application.